# make img draggable in td elements

Tags: php, jquery, foreach, draggable

```
foreach($photos as $photo) {
        $lastChild = "";
        if( $count%3 == 0 && $count != 0 )
            echo "</tr><tr>";
        $count++;
        ?> <td>

                <a href="<?php echo ($photo['source'])?>" title="<?php echo      ($photo['name'])?>">   


                <img id="thumb" class="thumb" src="<?php echo ($photo['picture'])?>">
                </a></td>
```

This is the script for draggable. Ive done this but it still does not work
only the first one 
does the foreach loop affects?

```
$thumb.draggable({
revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
helper: "clone",
    });
```

im unable to set ui-draggable to all the img src other than the first img.

any one can help?

Comment: $('.thumb').draggable(); - but if you're looking for more specific stuff, we need your code.. and need to know exactly what doesn't work - maybe a js fiddle will help

Comment: I've added the jquery code above

Comment: Also ideally you want to use an id only once. Are you using them at all? If not, ditch them and use what @Sam said above.

Comment: I'm using cakephp framework.
its in .ctp
whats html validated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<img class="thumb" src="<?php echo ($photo['picture'])?>">
```

instead of

```
<img id="thumb" class="thumb" src="<?php echo ($photo['picture']); ?>" />
```

in your PHP and

```
$('.thumb').draggable({
```

instead of

```
$thumb.draggable({
```

in your jQuery. This should fix it.

If you absolutely need IDs on the images for any reason, make them unique like this:

```
<img id="thumb-<?php echo $count; ?>" class="thumb" src="<?php echo ($photo['picture'])?>">
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628095/how-do-i-use-an-image-in-the-droppable-area-to-upload-to-the-server-using-jquery

anyone knows how to solve this?